# What's wrong with this implementation of Awaiter in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, task

So I was trying to make a simple awaitable struct that allow my to return a bool:

```
// define a special container for returning results
public struct BoolResult {
    public bool Value;
    public BoolAwaiter GetAwaiter () {
        return new BoolAwaiter(Value);
    }
}

// make the interface task-like
public readonly struct BoolAwaiter : INotifyCompletion {
    private readonly bool _Input;

    // wrap the async operation
    public BoolAwaiter (bool value) {
        _Input = value;
    }

    // is task already done (yes)
    public bool IsCompleted {
        get { return true; }
    }

    // wait until task is done (never called)
    public void OnCompleted (Action continuation) => continuation?.Invoke();

    // return the result
    public bool GetResult () {
        return _Input;
    }
}
```

And I was using it like:

```
private async BoolResult LoadAssets (string label) {
    //
    // some await asyncFunction here
    //

    // then at the end
    return new BoolResult { Value = true };
}
```

But I still get this compile error:

> `error CS1983: The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>`

I thought my `BoolResult` was already Task-like? What's the issue here?

Comment: Is `BoolResult` a `Task` or `Task<T>`?

Comment: dammit, had a long answer in progress... oh well; short version: your type is *awaitable* at the consumer side, i.e. `await someBoolResult` - but you need extra glue for it to work on the **producer** side, i.e. `async BoolResult` in a method signature. However, the code you show doesn't actually need `async` in the signature - if you remove the `async` from `private async BoolResult`, it should work and should be awaitable at the consumer

Comment: @MarcGravell I wasn't completely sure of the duplicate, since I then found [this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781785286650/5/ch05lvl1sec37/implementing-a-custom-awaitable-type) that suggests something more like this code should be supported. Was that closure good?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yeah, I think it is good - I just added a tiny bit of context / clarification about producer vs consumer. The link you posted to is *also* talking about consumer, which again : is fine; the actual question here, and in the dup-close, is : about *producer*. So: yeah, close is fine, I think

Comment: just as some guidance for @bitinn - the number of times you should roll your own awaitable is now basically zero; I have an in-progress (i.e. incomplete) blog post talking about this at great length, but if possible: prefer `ValueTask<bool>`. There are great ways of doing this that bypass `Task` even in the incomplete case.

Comment: Wait, there is a ValueTask? I mean if it's a struct then I am ok with using it. On the other hand, I do have some `await` within `LoadAssets` method (edited the question), so I still need the `async` on it.

Comment: Also the linked SO question seems a bit confusing to me: what I did was the bare minimum of a task-like struct, the linked SO seem to complicate things further for reasons I don't fully understand.

Comment: OK I got it now I need a builder type, should have read this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/task-types.md

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Can I request to reopen it, now I realize my problem is with Unity 2018.3, which AFAIK, doesn't have AsyncMethodBuilder attribute in the CompilerServices namespace (and yet it supports C# 7, so I am confused why not). I will add the unity tag.